# MVC4 Enum Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model which I am passing to a view. This model has a property of type enum. For example, State i.e. State.Texas, State.Alaska.

I wish to populate the state in a label/textbox. How can I parse the enum to the label/textbox in the view?

Answer (score 2):

You may create a view model for your view with ***VIEW SPECIFIC Properties***.Have a string property for your state. set the value of that in your action and use that.

```
public class UserProfileVM
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  //Other properties for your view as needed

  public string State { set;get;}
}
```

and in the action method set the value from whatever source you have(enum or anything else

```
public ActionResult Show()
{ 
  var vm=new UserProfileVM();
  vm.State="Texas";  // You can replace this and read from your enum
  return View(vm);    
}
```

and in the view

```
@model UserProfileVM
@Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.State)
```

Comment: The intermediary view model should not be necessary in this case.  They stated they already have a model they are passing to the view.  MVC will automatically convert the enum to a string for display and parse it back during model binding.

Answer (score 1):

To display the value of the enum in a textbox or label use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.State)` or `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.State)` respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "with a grid".  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry. For instance if i use a WebGrid

Comment: Oh, I think you might be confused how ASP.NET MVC works.  You do not use controls in MVC.  In MVC you have helpers that render/generate HTML, like `@Html.TextBoxFor()` for example.

Comment: You can use the WebGrid. But I am unsure how i can populate enums;   var grid = new WebGrid(Model.State, fieldNamePrefix: "gridItems_", pageFieldName: "inside");

Comment: You are right, I was confused and thought the WebGrid was a control from Web Forms but it's a helper that's part of WebMatrix.  I am not familiar with this particular helper and have just rolled my own table functionality.

Comment: I think when you instantiate the WebGrid you need to pass it the whole Model and not just the one `Model.State` property.